# Graphing arrays with different lengths on the same Pandas graph

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, indexing

`a` and `b` are datetime indexes for the `A Values` and `B Values`, respectively . The size of the `A Values` is greater than that of the `B Values` I want to reproduce a code where I place them on the same graph. How would I be able to write a code where it graphs 2 numpy array with different lengths on the same graph?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

a = np.array(['2017-09-15 07:11:00', '2017-09-15 12:11:00', '2017-12-22 06:35:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
b = np.array(['2017-09-10 02:25:00', '2017-12-11 03:11:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')


graph= pd.DataFrame({
   'A Values': np.array([11,-3,4]),
   'B Values': np.array([2,4])
   }, index= [a,b]).plot.line()
```

Error Code:

```
ValueError: all arrays must be same length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pad the arrays to same size with filling small array to zero or none :
use this snippet to make it :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

a = np.array(['2017-09-15 07:11:00', '2017-09-15 12:11:00', '2017-12-22 06:35:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
b = np.array(['2017-09-10 02:25:00', '2017-12-11 03:11:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

s1=[11,-3,4]
s2=[2,4]

m = max(len(s1),len(s2))
a1=[None] * m
a2=[None] * m
ax1=[None] * m
ax2=[None] * m

for i in range(len(s1)):
    a1[i] = s1[i]
    ax1[i]=a[i]
for i in range(len(s2)):
    a2[i] = s2[i]
    ax2[i]=b[i]

graph= pd.DataFrame({
   'A Values': np.array(a1),
   'B Values': np.array(a2)
   }, index= [ax1,ax2]).plot.line()
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=5) 
#labelsize=5 instead of labelsize=10
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

I hope you find it useful

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution but I would like the x plot to be the datetime values if possible, so 'a` and `b`

Comment: Also `a values` looks wrong why does it has 3 plots should only have 2

Comment: I changed the code to what you wanted. enjoy it. :)

Comment: thank you could you explain what the functions  `a1, ...ax2= [None]* m ` does as well as what the for loops with the range of s1 and s2 are used for. Thank you.

Comment: [None]* m generate none array(array size is m) and with for loop, fill this none array with value . Eventually, we have two array with same size.

Answer (score 0):

Just catch the axis object generated by matplotlib for the first plot and use it to plot the second series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


a = np.array(['2017-09-15 07:11:00', '2017-09-15 12:11:00', '2017-12-22 06:35:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
b = np.array(['2017-09-10 02:25:00', '2017-12-11 03:11:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')    

ax1 = pd.DataFrame({'A Values': np.array([11,-3,4])}, index= a).plot.line()       
pd.DataFrame({'B Values': np.array([2,4])}, index= b).plot.line(ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

In case you were wondering what [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py) has to do with your question - unless specified otherwise, pandas gives the data to matplotlib to generate plots.